# How to find maven entries for any project

Tags: maven

Is there a standard way for finding maven entries for any project? For eg if I talk about Spring MVC. Do I need to go the Spring website and find a section there or is there some other standard procedure using which I can find the entries I need to make ?

Comment: I found this beautiful link: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/wiki/Downloading-Spring-artifacts . This is the kind of information which every project should publish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You can find them in the ordinary maven repositories:

- http://mvnrepository.com/
- http://search.maven.org/

You search for the artificat you want, and get the pom info to include in your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I just google "maven" and the package name. Some artifacts are only made public in company repos.

Answer (score 0):

I search **com.x.y.z maven coordinates** on google and almost every time I get the results.